# Show Last Month of Last Year sales in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a SQL query from a database that is linked to Excel that will give me all the sales on specific customers. I wanted to take the current date, 5/27/15 and look at the sales at the end of last month, last year, 4/31/14. So in the future if the date was 6/12/15 I'd want to see 5/31/15.

Here's what I currently have.

```
SELECT   CustomerName, 
         SUM(NetSales) AS YTD_Sales
FROM     dbo.AllSales
WHERE    (CustomerClass = 'DLR') 
  AND    (CustomerName IN ('Company 1', 'Company2')) 
  AND    (InvoiceDate BETWEEN '1/1/2015' 
  AND DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) 
  AND (CustomerClass = 'DLR')
  GROUP BY CustomerName
```

This code gives me all sales up to the end of the month last month. I feel like I'm close.

Comment: @MarcB Its Sql Server

Comment: Please avoid using between operator, it can cause you bugs, better to use InvoiceDate >= XXX and InvoiceDate < YYY instead of deducting one second

Comment: So you would only want the sum of the sales of April 2014 for today's date for example? And for June 1st 2015, you would want the sum of the sales for May 2014? I'm just try to understand the question more.

Comment: I would also advise not to use short hand versions of the dateadd / datediff parameters. You might cause issues when you accidentally use the wrong one. For example m = month, but y is not year, it is day of year.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to capture data up to the last day of the previous month for the previous year. If I decide to run my report on a random day, lets say 7/18/2015, then I want to see everything up until 6/31/14. The end of the previous month and the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

The question was slighly unclear, but if you want now the data from 1.1.2014 - 31.4.2014, this is how you can get it:

```
SELECT   
    CustomerName, 
    SUM(NetSales) AS YTD_Sales
FROM     
    dbo.AllSales
WHERE    
    CustomerClass = 'DLR' and
    CustomerName IN ('Company 1', 'Company2') and
    InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(year, datediff(year, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) and
    InvoiceDate < DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0)
GROUP BY 
    CustomerName
```

If it was something else, you can adjust the -12 and -1 in the dateadd to get correct months included.